# JPQL query: selecting a single Boolean which is the AND of two of object's fields

Tags: java, jpa, jpql, criteriaquery

Suppose that I have a JPA-annotated class called `MyData` with a primary identifier field (`BigDecimal` type called "primaryID"), and two `Boolean` fields called "fieldA" and "fieldB".  What I want to do is create a JPA query that will select `fieldA AND fieldB` for a given `MyData` instance.

```
        final CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        final CriteriaQuery<Boolean> boolQuery = builder.createQuery(Boolean.class);
        final Root<MyData> data = boolQuery.from(MyData.class);
        boolQuery.select(builder.isTrue(builder.and(data.<Boolean> get("fieldA"),
                profile.<Boolean> get("fieldB"))));
        final Predicate primaryIDPredicate = builder.equal(profile.<BigDecimal> get("primaryID"),
                1000);
        boolQuery.where(primaryIDPredicate);

        final TypedQuery<Boolean> myQuery = entityManager.createQuery(boolQuery);
```

When my `entityManager` executes this query, I get: `org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: and near line 1...`.  This leads me to believe that I need something different (other than the `builder.isTrue` method) to designate that I want to take a Boolean and of two fields of my object.  Any ideas on how I should construct this query?

Comment: Why does the title says "JPQL", when in question you say that you need to construct JPA query?

Comment: I understand "JPQL" to mean "using the JPA query language."  Whether that means creating a JPA string query (parametrized or not), or using the CriteriaBuilder/CriteriaQuery, I don't particularly care.  If there is a bug in the terminology I have used, I will update the question.

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo myself. There are actually two main approaches for building queries in JPA: 1) **JPQL**. Example: `SELECT a, b FROM C` 2) Type-safe **Criteria Query API**. You use the latter in your example.

Comment: Look carefully at your `SELECT` expression. What you're trying to do is something like this `SELECT fieldA = 1 AND fieldB = 1 FROM MyData` which is, of course, not a valid SQL. You can't specify predicates in the `SELECT` clause. Now think about the SQL query  you're trying to reproduce, and I'll try to help you, to write it in Criteria API.

Comment: Hmm, you're right.  It looks like you can't actually have boolean based expressions as columns in a select clause,at least with the underlying RDBMS we're using.  I had just assumed it was possible since you can always do something like `SELECT 1+1`, and I didn't see what was special about booleans vs integers.

Anyway, I got it to work simply by making the booleans part of the where clause instead, and checking for whether there were more than 0 rows in the return set.

Comment: Glad, you solved your problem. Now you can post your solution and accept your own answer, so that everyone could see, that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, what I ended up doing was simply moving the booleans I wanted to "AND" into the predicate instead, and just checking whether anything was returned.  Of course, I could have simply retrieved the entire object (MyData) based on the primary ID, and done the "AND" in Java code, but the point was to avoid fetching the full object because it has a large number of nested joins to its referenced collections, and those would be unnecessary for this case.

```
        final CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        final CriteriaQuery<BigInteger> primaryIDQuery = builder.createQuery(BigInteger.class);
        final Root<MyData> data = primaryIDQuery.from(MyData.class);
        primaryIDQuery.select(data.<BigInteger> get("primaryId"));
        final Predicate primaryIDPredicate = builder.equal(profile.<BigInteger> get("primaryId"),1000);
        final Predicate otherPredicate = builder.or(
                builder.isTrue(profile.<Boolean> get("fieldA")),
                builder.isTrue(profile.<Boolean> get("fieldB")));
        primaryIDQuery.where(primaryIDPredicate , otherPredicate);

        final TypedQuery<BigInteger> existenceQuery = entityManager.createQuery(primaryIDQuery);

        boolean whatIWant = existenceQuery.getResultList().size() > 0;
```